# вызов фукции для значений метода

Tags: javascript, canvas

Подскажите, пожалуйста как вызвать функцию для всех значений метода. Вот пример

```js
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvasGame"),
          ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
          currentHeight = window.innerHeight / 2;
    canvas.height = currentHeight;
    canvas.width = currentHeight;

    let pathArr = []; //Создаём массив, в котором будем хранить все пути

    const btnSize = currentHeight / 3;

    function createRect(recX, recY) {
        let path = new Path2D();
        path.rect(recX, recY, btnSize, btnSize);
        path.closePath();
        colorizeRect(path);
        pathArr.push(path);
    }

    const rects = {
        1:{x:0, y:0},
        2:{x:btnSize,  y:0},
        3:{x:btnSize * 2, y:0},
        4:{x:0, y:btnSize},
        5:{x:btnSize, y:btnSize},
        6:{x:btnSize * 2, y:btnSize},
        7:{x:0, y:btnSize * 2},
        8:{x:btnSize, y:btnSize * 2},
        9:{x:btnSize * 2, y:btnSize * 2}
    };

    console.log();

    rects.createRect = function(){


    };

    function countProperties(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).length;
    }

    console.log("count =" + countProperties(rects));
```

```css
#canvasGame{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasGame"></canvas>
```

Как вызвать функцию для создания прямоугольников на холсте. И ещё вопрос, почему при подсчете количества элементов метода countProperties вываливается 10, хотя ключей 9 ?

Comment: под значениями метод имееться в виду `const rects` ? тоесть проблема в тому, чтоб перебрать в цикле значения и визвать функу `createRect` ?

Comment: Да, в этом. Я пробую через цикл for, но явно что-то не так делаю. И ещё длинна смущает

Comment: ок, щасс какой-то пример придумаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const btnSize = 222 / 3;

function createRect(recX, recY) {
  console.log(`createRect, x=[${recX}], y=[${recY}]`)
}

const rects = {
  1: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  2: {
    x: btnSize,
    y: 0
  },
  3: {
    x: btnSize * 2,
    y: 0
  },
  4: {
    x: 0,
    y: btnSize
  },
  5: {
    x: btnSize,
    y: btnSize
  },
  6: {
    x: btnSize * 2,
    y: btnSize
  },
  7: {
    x: 0,
    y: btnSize * 2
  },
  8: {
    x: btnSize,
    y: btnSize * 2
  },
  9: {
    x: btnSize * 2,
    y: btnSize * 2
  }
};

//// ето тоже ключ обьекта, тот 10-тый
//// поетому фильтруем ключи, оставляем только числа
//rects.createRect = function() {
//  const that = this
//  Object.keys(that).filter(k => !isNaN(k)).forEach(k2 => {
//    createRect.call(null, that[k2].x, that[k2].y)
//  })
//};

// Пример "попроще"
rects.createRect = function() {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this)) {
    if (!isNaN(key))
      createRect.call(null, value.x, value.y)
  }
};

rects.createRect()
```

Саму отрисовку удалил, оставил только вызов метода.

Если что-то не понятно, задавайте вопросы

Comment: добавил пример, как мен кажеться проще для восприятия

Comment: @BlackStar1991 а понять просто, получаем ключи обьекта `Object.keys`, фильтруем ключи(оставляя только числа) `filter`, перебираем в цикле ключи `forEach` и на каждой итерации перебора зовем функу `createRect`, передавая туда параметри, которие получаем по поточному ключу с нашего обьекта

Comment: тогда ещё вопрос, а почему раз в функцию createRect передаются значения, то эти прямоугольники не отрисовываются ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 ну я саму функцию удалил, оставив только вивод в консоль, чисто показать передачу параметров и визов функи

Answer (score 1):

Вы добавили десятое свойство:

```
rects.createRect = ...
```